# Which indicators to use for measuring stochastic-volatility behaviour and/or seasonal effects?

Tags: time-series, classification, forecasting, stochastic-processes, seasonality

## Context

I have a vector with 1000 time series, I would like to create a workflow to classify them as described in the following pseudocode:

Time_series ( is a vector of time series)

```
For ts in time_series:

Idx1=Meassure_index_1(ts)
Idx2=Meassure_index_2(ts)

If idx1 >= yield:
   # is a seasonal time series
If idx2 >= yield:
  # is a stochastic-volatility time series
```

Which index could I use to avoid visualizing them in order to classify them?